# How to track Pentaho HTTPPOST soap request using fiddler

Tags: caching, http-post, pentaho, fiddler

In our BI process we do HTTPPOST soap request in loop. We have doubt pentaho cache the first response and return cache version of response on each subsequent request.

Is it possible to trace the request using fiddler or any other tool. I tried using fiddler with no luck.

Please guide>>

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

`Pentaho` appears to be based on Java, which doesn't always pick up the system's default proxy settings. You may need to manually configure the JVM's settings (http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/ConfigureJavaApp) unless the tool itself offers a proxy configuration UI, e.g. http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/HTTP or http://pedroalves-bi.blogspot.com/2014/07/using-pentaho-marketplace-over-proxy-or.html